# Finding the limits of a trig function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I have been struggling with finding the following limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{\cos x + 1}{x - \pi}
$$

Use of L'Hospital's rule is not permitted.
Thanks

Comment: In fact, l'Hoptial's Rule would arguably be circular in this case.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(\pi)}{x-\pi}=...$$

Comment: Your first limit is wrong, I think it should be $+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

Note that: $\cos(x)=-\cos(x-\pi)$:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos(x)+1}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{-\cos(x-\pi)+1}{x-\pi}$$

The Taylor series of cosine (which has infinite radius of convergence):
$$\cos(x)=1-x^2/2+O(x^4)$$

Substitute $x-\pi$ into the taylor series:
$$\cos(x-\pi)=1-(x-\pi)^2/2+O((x-\pi)^4)$$

---

Alternatively you could simply calculate the taylor series of $\cos(x)$ evaluated at $x=\pi$.

---

Plug this into the previous limit:
$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{-1+(x-\pi)^2/2-O((x-\pi)^4)+1}{x-\pi}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \pi}[(x-\pi)/2-O((x-\pi)^3)]=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x-\pi=t$, so $x=\pi+t$ and $\cos x=\cos(\pi+t)=-\cos t$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos^2t}{t}\frac{1}{1+\cos t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}\frac{t}{1+\cos t}=\dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

I like Surb's approach.

Here is annother.

$\lim_\limits{x\to\pi} \frac{\cos(x) +1}{x-\pi}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to\pi} \frac{\cos(x-\pi + \pi) +1}{x-\pi}\\
u = x - pi\\
\lim_\limits{u\to0} \frac{\cos(u + \pi) +1}{u}\\
\cos (u+\pi) = -\cos u\\
\lim_\limits{u\to0} \frac{1-\cos u}{u}$

Which you may have already encountered.